# Chef-solo cannot locate an nginx recipe template

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, deployment, chef, chef-solo

I have been recently experimenting with Chef.  I thought I would attempt to rebuild my personal web server using chef-solo.  It's an AWS instance running the Amazon 64bit Linux AMI.

**My first objective** is to install nginx.  I have cloned the Opscode cookbook repository, and am using [their nginx cookbook](https://github.com/opscode/cookbooks/tree/master/nginx).

**My problem** appears to be that chef-solo cannot find a template after it has started the process.

The command I'm using is

```
 chef-solo -j /etc/chef/dna.json
```

*dna.json*

```
{
  "nginx": {
    "user": "ec2-user"
  },
  "recipes": [ "nginx" ]
}
```

*solo.rb*

```
file_cache_path "/var/chef-solo"
cookbook_path "/var/chef-solo/cookbooks"
```

...*the output*

```
[root@ip-10-202-221-135 chef-solo]# chef-solo -j /etc/chef/dna.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/systemu-2.2.0/lib/systemu.rb:29: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
[Fri, 27 Jan 2012 19:41:36 +0000] INFO: *** Chef 0.10.8 ***
[Fri, 27 Jan 2012 19:41:37 +0000] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["nginx"] from JSON
[Fri, 27 Jan 2012 19:41:37 +0000] INFO: Run List is [recipe[nginx]]
[Fri, 27 Jan 2012 19:41:37 +0000] INFO: Run List expands to [nginx]
[Fri, 27 Jan 2012 19:41:37 +0000] INFO: Starting Chef Run for ip-10-202-221-135.ec2.internal
[Fri, 27 Jan 2012 19:41:37 +0000] INFO: Running start handlers
[Fri, 27 Jan 2012 19:41:37 +0000] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[Fri, 27 Jan 2012 19:41:37 +0000] INFO: Missing gem 'mysql'
[Fri, 27 Jan 2012 19:41:38 +0000] INFO: Processing package[nginx] action install (nginx::default line 21)
[Fri, 27 Jan 2012 19:41:39 +0000] INFO: Processing directory[/var/log/nginx] action create (nginx::default line 23)
[Fri, 27 Jan 2012 19:41:39 +0000] INFO: Processing template[/usr/sbin/nxensite] action create (nginx::default line 30)
[Fri, 27 Jan 2012 19:41:39 +0000] INFO: Processing template[/usr/sbin/nxdissite] action create (nginx::default line 30)
[Fri, 27 Jan 2012 19:41:39 +0000] INFO: Processing template[nginx.conf] action create (nginx::default line 38)
[Fri, 27 Jan 2012 19:41:39 +0000] INFO: Processing template[/etc/nginx/sites-available/default] action create (nginx::default line 46)
[Fri, 27 Jan 2012 19:41:39 +0000] INFO: template[/etc/nginx/sites-available/default] mode changed to 644
[Fri, 27 Jan 2012 19:41:39 +0000] ERROR: template[/etc/nginx/sites-available/default] (nginx::default line 46) has had an error
[Fri, 27 Jan 2012 19:41:39 +0000] ERROR: template[/etc/nginx/sites-available/default] (/var/chef-solo/cookbooks/nginx/recipes/default.rb:46:in `from_file') had an error:
template[/etc/nginx/sites-available/default] (nginx::default line 46) had an error: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - (/tmp/chef-rendered-template20120127-29441-1yp55vz, /etc/nginx/sites-available/default)
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:519:in `rename'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:519:in `block in mv'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1515:in `block in fu_each_src_dest'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1531:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1513:in `fu_each_src_dest'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:508:in `mv'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/provider/template.rb:47:in `block in action_create'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/mixin/template.rb:48:in `block in render_template'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb:316:in `open'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/mixin/template.rb:45:in `render_template'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/provider/template.rb:99:in `render_with_context'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/provider/template.rb:39:in `action_create'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/resource.rb:440:in `run_action'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/runner.rb:45:in `run_action'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in converge'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `each'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block in converge'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:94:in `block in execute_each_resource'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call_iterator_block'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:92:in `execute_each_resource'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/runner.rb:76:in `converge'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/client.rb:312:in `converge'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/client.rb:160:in `run'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:192:in `block in run_application'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:183:in `loop'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:183:in `run_application'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/lib/chef/application.rb:67:in `run'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-0.10.8/bin/chef-solo:25:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/chef-solo:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/chef-solo:19:in `<main>'
[Fri, 27 Jan 2012 19:41:39 +0000] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[Fri, 27 Jan 2012 19:41:39 +0000] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[Fri, 27 Jan 2012 19:41:39 +0000] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef-solo/chef-stacktrace.out
[Fri, 27 Jan 2012 19:41:39 +0000] FATAL: Errno::ENOENT: template[/etc/nginx/sites-available/default] (nginx::default line 46) had an error: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - (/tmp/chef-rendered-template20120127-29441-1yp55vz, /etc/nginx/sites-available/default)
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

To fix you should probably add this to the beginning of your nginx default recipe:

```
directory "/etc/nginx/sites-available" do
    owner "root"
    group "root"
    mode "0755"
end
```

For what it's worth, I've been doing the same thing with Chef (Hosted), EC2 and Amazon Linux. It took me a while, but I figured out that it was almost always easier to just roll my own recipes. I now have a dozen that I now use, and I've removed all the Opscode shared ones I initially tried.

In fact, my default recipe for nginx has just one line:

```
`package "nginx"`
```

So one way to go is to install that on your server first with `yum install nginx` and then grab the default config file it created. Bring that back to your cookbook as a template, and put in ERB lines to customize any values for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a directory in the tree `/etc/nginx/sites-available` doesn't exist and ought to be created.

If you want to add to the opscode recipe, here's how you can have chef create the directory for you:

http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Resources#Resources-Directory